# Most Popular/Recently Updated Wiki page

Tags: wiki

I want to display in a webpart whats the top 5 ( **recenlty updated and Most Popular wiki** Pages). By most Popular I mean not be **STAR rating** but the **most visited** Wiki page.

How do I do it? My idea is to add a custom feild to a list and update the increment Counter when ever the page is visited and then display the pages with the maximum count.

Comment: You could pull from the site usage page for each wiki site...

Comment: Can you display the site usage in Web part?

Comment: Not out of the box, but you can create a simple webpart that pulls from the data in the site usage... Why reinvent the wheel by incrementing a value for each site hit?

Comment: How do I get the data in the site usage? Can you point me in the direction on how to go about it. I can create the webpart using coding from Visual studio 2010. I have sharepoint 2010.Also access to Sharepoint Designer

Comment: You will use the SPWeb.GetUsageData method in order to pull the siteusage from the site that you are requesting.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getusagedata.aspx

Answer (score 2):

is using web analytics a possibility for you? see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/03/21/introducing-web-analytics-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

I believe there are some out of the box webparts that can show most visited pages and things like that

Comment: Now this will get me the most visited pages. I need to check from the user if they want the most clicked paged or the most viewed page. Will post later.

Comment: another, complete different solution, would be to use google analytics and use that info to integrate in your site. javascript can be included using a CEWP

Comment: google analytics  does it give the most clicked pages?

Comment: out of the box webparts that can show most visited pages ? I found none. ccan you let me know what hey are. I dont mind buying them

Answer (score 1):

There is a web analytics web part with SharePoint 2010 that will give you the popularity ratings and most viewed content. It is included in SharePoint Server.